# Responsive table handling in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

When a table's width exceed the span's width, like this page: http://jsfiddle.net/rcHdC/

You will see the table's content is outside of the `span`.

What would be the best method to cater this case?

Comment: What would you like to happen?

Answer (score 153):

[Bootstrap 3](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2013/08/19/bootstrap-3-released/) now has Responsive tables out of the box. Hooray! :)

You can check it here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#tables-responsive

Add a `<div class="table-responsive">` surrounding your table and you should be good to go:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

To make it work on all layouts you can do this:

```
.table-responsive
{
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Comment: But it only applies it to small devices (under 768px) :S Source: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive

Comment: To enable this on all size layouts, you can just drop the responsive styles from the 768 block in the foundation_and_overrides.css.scss file. Something like ``` .table-responsive {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
 }
```

Comment: @ase69s check my updated answer. Just now I needed it on a table with lots of columns. Adding `overflow-x: auto` in a custom `CSS` file does the trick for larger display layouts.

Comment: You may like to add the border into that syle definition, too, for consistency: `border: 1px solid #dddddd;`

Comment: Thanks. The last tip there (overriding `overflow-x`) did the trick better than anything else I have tried.

Comment: Might also want to add `.table-responsive td, .table-responsive th { white-space:nowrap; }` to ensure the cells don't automatically shrink and add line breaks.

Answer (score 21):

One option that is available is fooTable. Works great on a Responsive website and allows you to set multiple breakpoints... [fooTable Link](http://themergency.com/footable/)

Comment: [FooTable is now built to work with Twitter Bootstrap out of the box.](http://fooplugins.com/footable/demos/getting-started.htm#setup)

Answer (score 18):

There are many different things you can do when dealing with responsive tables.

I personally like this approach by Chris Coyier:

- http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

You can find many other alternatives here:

- http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-table-roundup/
- http://bradfrost.github.io/this-is-responsive/patterns.html#tables

If you can leverage Bootstrap and get something quickly, you can simply use the class names ".hidden-phone" and ".hidden-tablet" to hide some rows but this approach might to be the best in many cases. More info (see "Responsive utility classes"):

- http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

Comment: +1 for the Coyer Link. I've used that in the past to great effect.

Comment: Yup, Chris Coyer's solution is very neat. Much nicer than the one provided by bootstrap or zurbfoundation (they simply add horizontal scroll).

Comment: As of now, January 2016, Coyier's and other's responsive stuff is 5 - 6 years old, before everyone started using Twitter Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Bootstrap 3 and Less you could apply the responsive tables to all resolutions by updatingthe file:

```
tables.less
```

or overwriting this part:

```
@media (max-width: @screen-xs) {
  .table-responsive {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    border: 1px solid @table-border-color;

    // Tighten up spacing and give a background color
    > .table {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      background-color: #fff;

      // Ensure the content doesn't wrap
      > thead,
      > tbody,
      > tfoot {
        > tr {
          > th,
          > td {
            white-space: nowrap;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // Special overrides for the bordered tables
    > .table-bordered {
      border: 0;

      // Nuke the appropriate borders so that the parent can handle them
      > thead,
      > tbody,
      > tfoot {
        > tr {
          > th:first-child,
          > td:first-child {
            border-left: 0;
          }
          > th:last-child,
          > td:last-child {
            border-right: 0;
          }
        }
        > tr:last-child {
          > th,
          > td {
            border-bottom: 0;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With:

```
@media (max-width: @screen-lg) {
  .table-responsive {
    width: 100%;
...
```

Note how I changed the first line @screen-XX value.

I know making all tables responsive may not sound that good, but I found it extremely useful  to have this enabled up to LG on large tables (lots of columns).

Hope it helps someone.