# How can i resize images in a table in twitter bootstrap?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

i want that the images in my table resize. How can I do that? Here my table code:

```
<table class='table' border='2'>
    <tr>
        <td class='click go0' id='1'><img src='../images/null.png'></td>
        <td class='click go0' id='2'><img src='../images/null.png'></td>
        <td class='click go0' id='3'><img src='../images/null.png'></td>
        ...
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

Comment: I tried to give the image a width and the table the class table

Comment: How did you do this? (show some code)

Comment: fibi, there's nothing in your code indicating how you're trying to resize your images. Are you using CSS? jQuery? Voodoo?

Comment: bootstrap should resize images automatic but it seams like not in a table not.

Answer (score 0):

On the bootstrap site, it says that tables are NOT responsive. You will have to put them in something else to make them responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap tables are not responsive by default, but there are a few options to work around this limitation.

Answers to [Responsive table handling in Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176714/responsive-table-handling-in-twitter-bootstrap) may be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like

```
table.table td img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```