# bootstrap 3 table-responsive not working with angularJS app, I am placing table inside ng-view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to angularjs and I am creating an table rows using `ng-repeat`.

Below is the code snippet

```
    <div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
             <th>heading1</th>
             <th>heading2</th>
             <th>heading3</th> 
             <th>heading4</th>
             <th>heading5</th> 
             <th>heading6</th>
             <th>heading7</th>
             <th>heading8</th>
             <th>heading9</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="task in taskList">
            <td>{{task.item1}}</td>
            <td>{{task.item2}}</td>
            <td>{{task.item3}}</td>
            <td>{{task.item4}}</td>
            <td>{{task.item5}}</td>
            <td>{{task.item6}}</td>
            <td>{{task.item7}}</td>
            <td>{{task.item8}}</td>
            <td>{{task.item9}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

and i am loading same in ng-view div

```
<div ng-view class="container-fluid"></div>
```

But when I see the above table in mobile mode of chrome browser, table is growing horizontally(out of device width). 
Same code works fine if I create a test page with same classes.
Let me know if anything I need to change to use in angular?

Comment: works fine for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/UA0CuJHC9XZaZZ27KuyQ?p=preview

Comment: Actually my code also same as yours,but for me its not working.

Comment: Do you have any console errors?

Comment: Works for me to, and seems like it's just a matter of not enough space. Check out the first solution proposed in this answer, worked great for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17208808/525445

Comment: Did you set the viewport in the head tag?  http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-mobile