# How to layout of the table is not broken when resize browser or run on mobile

Tags: php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have problem with table (html-bootstrap). When I resize the browser and then it has been broken Like image below:

Table Display at the first time, when i'm not resize browser
[image]

After resize browser, It has got problem like this image
[image]

This is my src html table and recently I have no solution for this, Plz help me to resolve it.

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="box col-md-12">
        <div class="box-inner">
        <div class="box-header well" data-original-title="">
        <h2><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> TimeSheet List</h2>
        <div class="box-icon">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-minimize btn-round btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    <div class="box-content">
     <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>TS ID</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Timesheet Date</th>
                <th>Date Approved</th>
                <th>From Time</th>
                <th>To Time</th>
                <th>Activity</th>
                <th>Division</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>Approved By</th>
                <th colspan="2"><strong>Actions</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="3">1</td>
                <td rowspan="3">Vasu</td>
                <td rowspan="3">2015-02-17</td>
                <td rowspan="3">2015-02-18</td>
                <td>08:30</td>
                <td>10:30</td>
                <td>CS8743</td>
                <td rowspan="3">Service</td>
                <td rowspan="3">Department 1</td>
                <td rowspan="3">Jimmy</td>
                <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">View</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>10:30</td>
                <td>12:30</td>
                <td>CS3474</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>13:30</td>
                <td>17:30</td>
                <td>Help</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">2</td>
                <td rowspan="2">Jack</td>
                <td rowspan="2">2015-02-18</td>
                <td rowspan="2">2015-02-19</td>
                <td>08:30</td>
                <td>12:30</td>
                <td>Idle</td>
                <td rowspan="2">Hoseshop</td>
                <td rowspan="2">Department 2</td>
                <td rowspan="2">Jimmy</td>
                <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">View</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>13:30</td>
                <td>17:30</td>
                <td>CS001</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Tim</td>
                <td>2015-02-19</td>
                <td>2015-02-20</td>
                <td>08:30</td>
                <td>17:30</td>
                <td>CS002</td>
                <td>Driver</td>
                <td>Department 3</td>
                <td>Jimmy</td>
                <td colspan="2">View</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>Huey</td>
                <td>2015-02-20</td>
                <td>2015-02-21</td>
                <td>08:30</td>
                <td>17:30</td>
                <td>CS003</td>
                <td>Project</td>
                <td>Department 4</td>
                <td>Jimmy</td>
                <td colspan="2">View</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>Hudo</td>
                <td>2015-02-21</td>
                <td>2015-02-22</td>
                <td>08:30</td>
                <td>17:30</td>
                <td>Help</td>
                <td>Piping</td>
                <td>Department 5</td>
                <td>Jimmy</td>
                <td colspan="2">View</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Plz. Help me!

Comment: Try add `table-responsive` as a class of your `table`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18347053/2788131

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the table in a div with the .table-responsive class. This will make the table scroll on smaller screens, but without making the whole page scroll.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered">...</table>
</div>
```

Docs: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive

Answer (score -1):

Use `table-responsive` `CSS` bootstrap class in your `<table>` element like so:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please feel free to accept the answer if it suited your requirements.