# How to make table responisve by using bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am new to bootrap, I need to create a responsive table by using Bootstrap. How to do that one please help me to achieve.
table which I need to make responsive its below.

Thanks in advance.

```html
<table class="table">
<thead>
<th>first name</th><th>second name</th><th>age</th><th>mobile no</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>  
    <td>50</td>
    <td>880482048</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>  
    <td>94</td>
  <td>880482048</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>  
    <td>80</td>
  <td>880482048</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>  
    <td>80</td>
  <td>880482048</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>  
    <td>80</td>
 <td>880482048</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Responsive table handling in Twitter Bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176714/responsive-table-handling-in-twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include in your code.
Just you need to include **div class="table-responsive"**    before table. thats it.

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>

<div class="container">                                                                              
 <div class="table-responsive">          
  <table class="table">
<thead>
<th>first name</th><th>second name</th><th>age</th><th>mobile no</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>  
    <td>50</td>
    <td>880482048</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>  
    <td>94</td>
  <td>880482048</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>  
    <td>80</td>
  <td>880482048</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>  
    <td>80</td>
  <td>880482048</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>  
    <td>80</td>
 <td>880482048</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Renuka.. Just one line make fully responsive table. nice. thanks to bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it responsive use the grid system, not a table. That's what the grid system is for. You can still use it to represent the same data. Just the html will look a little different.

Comment: Thanks James for your advice.(Y)