# Bootstrap 3 Navbar Moves Off Screen on iPhone

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table that expands in width off screen on a button click and after doing so the collapsed mobile menu disappears off screen to the right with it, but it only happens on my phone.  Even mobile browser emulators seems to not have an issue.  I am having trouble emulating this solution on a computer but here is the fiddle.  I am running Safari on an iPhone 7.

https://jsfiddle.net/z8zLe19w/9/

HTML

```
  <body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div><a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Brand</a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">One</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">two</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<section>
<div class="container">
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="populateTable()">Populate Table</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="clearTable()">Clear Table</button>
  </div>
</form>
<div class="row">
  <table class='table table-striped' id="data-table">
    <tr>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>Col2</th>
      <th>Col3</th>
      <th>Col4</th>
      <th>Col5</th>
      <th>Col6</th>
      <th>Col7</th>
      <th>Col8</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</div><!-- End container -->
</section>
```

CSS

```
section {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

Javascript

```
function populateTable() {
  var data_table = document.getElementById('data-table');
  var new_row = data_table.insertRow(-1);  
  for(var i=0;i<8;i++) {
    var new_cell = new_row.insertCell(-1);
    new_cell.innerHTML = "Daaaaaattttaaaaaaaaa";
  }
}

function clearTable() {
  var data_table = document.getElementById('data-table');
  while(data_table.rows.length > 1) {
    data_table.deleteRow(-1);
  }
}
```

Comment: I found bootstraps "table-responsive" table class, but it doesn't seem to have solved my problem.  http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive I guess this is a common issue getting responsive tables to work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was a duplicate of [Responsive table handling in Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176714/responsive-table-handling-in-twitter-bootstrap)  I added class

```
table-responsive
```

to my `<div class="row">` which surrounds my table so `<div class="row table-responsive">` and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Add position fixed to the section.

```
section {
  padding-top: 60px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: This seems to have fixed the collapsed menu from disappearing off screen, but now I'm unable to scroll down to see the remaining table data down below.  I also had to move my footer into the section element or else it would overlay the table data.